# Is it possible to make an array via PowerShell in this case?

Tags: powershell

So I have a code:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Capabilities\FileAssociations" -Name .bmp -Type String -Value PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Bitmap -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Capabilities\FileAssociations" -Name .jpg -Type String -Value PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Jpeg -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Capabilities\FileAssociations" -Name .jpe -Type String -Value PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Jpeg -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Capabilities\FileAssociations" -Name .jpeg -Type String -Value PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Jpeg -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Capabilities\FileAssociations" -Name .png -Type String -Value PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Png -Force
```

and is it possible to make an array via PowerShell like something like this:

```
ForEach ($type in @(
".bmp"
".jpg"
".jpe"
"jpeg"
".png"
))
{
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Capabilities\FileAssociations" -Name $type -Type String -Value $something -Force
}
```

Or i'll be pointless?

Comment: ...What are you actually asking here?

Comment: I mean, will it be right to issue this code into something with array?

Comment: It's less code if you do, so probably. Fundamentally you get the same result either way so it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there's no 1-to-1 relationship between the file extension and file type, you might want to go with a hashtable:

```
$PVPrefix = 'PhotoViewer.FileAssoc'
$Assocs = @{
    ".bmp" = "Bitmap"
    ".jpg" = "Jpeg"
    ".jpe" = "Jpeg"
    ".jpeg" = "Jpeg"
    ".png" = "Png"
}
foreach($ext in $Assocs.Keys){
    New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Capabilities\FileAssociations" -Name $ext -Type String -Value "$PVPrefix.$($Assocs[$ext])" -Force
}
```